# Accessible screenreading of JavaFX "console" output

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a simple UI that is accessible for screenreaders. I've been mostly successful, but I can't manage to design the UI in a way that has the screenreader read new text output.

Currently, I have a `TextArea` displaying the output of an anonymous `PrintStream` created and set by `System.setOut`. Sometimes I open up a `TextField` for string inputs, but I've been working with just the `TextArea` to test the reading of text (for now it just listens for keystrokes to display more text for testing purposes).

The issue is this: when new text is added via System.out to the `TextArea`, the screenreader does not read it. I am still able to navigate upward with the arrow keys to read what was added but it is not read when first added. Is there any way to get the screenreader to treat my `TextArea` more like a standard console (in which it reads all new text automatically)? I'm using NVDA.

Things I have tried: 
- Using `TextArea.notifyAccessibleAttributeChanged(AccessibleAttribute.TEXT)` 
- Using `TextArea.requestFocus()` and `TextArea.notifyAccessibleAttributeChanged(AccessibleAttribute.FOCUS_NODE)` 
- Disabling autoflush on the `PrintStream` while using `TextArea.setAccessibleText(theNewText)` during a flush 
- Using a hidden `Label` set to the new text and focusing on it (I'm still fiddling with this one; Screenreaders can't read actual "hidden" text so I'm trying to find a way to draw it but also be "invisible", perhaps behind the `TextArea` somehow) 
- Changing focus to another `Node` and back, which doesn't work as I like because it reads the other `Node`s accessible stuff and then reads the entire body of the `TextArea` 
- Various combinations of these

I just can't seem to get it to work. I feel like I'm missing something simple and obvious here, but the JavaFX Accessibility API is still relatively new and I can't find solutions to specific problems like this one.

Here's the relevant code of my `Application`, if it helps any:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        root = new BorderPane();
        root.setFocusTraversable(false);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        //Create middle
        output = new TextArea();
        output.setEditable(false);
        output.setFocusTraversable(false); //I've tried true also, just to test
        output.setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.TEXT_AREA);
        root.setCenter(output);
        ...
        //Begin
        primaryStage.show();
        Thread th = new Thread(new AppMain());
        th.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void init() {
    //Set output to TextArea
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            appendTextArea(String.valueOf((char) b));
        }
    }, true)); //I've also overriden flush while this is false, see above
}

public void appendTextArea(String str) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        output.appendText(str);
    });
}
```

I seriously appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide. I've been messing with this small issue for way too long, and I'm still new to JavaFX. Thank you!

Comment: can you try using the textArea's textProperty()? and see, i know right but just try and see

Comment: Use it how? What should be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working example based off of your code.

**Disclosure**: For the screen reader I'm using the "Voice Over Utility" on my Mac, but hopefully that doesn't differ too much from your environment.

The key was to utilize the [Control#executeAccessibleAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#executeAccessibleAction-javafx.scene.AccessibleAction-java.lang.Object...-) method.

**Example**:

```
TextArea.executeAccessibleAction(AccessibleAction.SET_TEXT_SELECTION, start, finish);
```

### The Application Class

```
package application;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.AccessibleAction;
import javafx.scene.AccessibleRole;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application
{
    private TextArea    output;
    private BorderPane  root;

    private final StringBuilder STR_BUFFER = new StringBuilder();
    private static final String NEW_LINE   = System.lineSeparator();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
            root = new BorderPane();
            root.setFocusTraversable(false);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Create middle
            output = new TextArea();
            output.setEditable(false);
            output.setFocusTraversable(true); // I've tried true also, just to test 

            // ----------------------------------------------
            // Tell the Screen Reader what it needs to access
            // ----------------------------------------------
            output.setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.TEXT_AREA);

            root.setCenter(output);
            // ...

            // Begin
            primaryStage.show();

            // start the thread
            Thread th = new Thread(new AppMain());
            th.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        // Set output to TextArea when we have a full string
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream()
        {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException
            {
                if (b == '\r')
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (b == '\n')
                {
                    final String text = STR_BUFFER.toString() + NEW_LINE;
                    appendTextArea(text);
                    STR_BUFFER.setLength(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    STR_BUFFER.append((char) b);
                }
            }
        }, true));
    }

    public void appendTextArea(String str)
    {
        Platform.runLater(() ->
        {
            int anchor = output.getText().length();

            output.appendText(str);

            // just to clear it
            output.positionCaret(0);

            // ----------------------------------------------
            // Tell the Screen Reader what it needs to do
            // ----------------------------------------------
            output.executeAccessibleAction(AccessibleAction.SET_TEXT_SELECTION, anchor, anchor + str.length());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### The Thread Class

```
/*
 * Just to simulate a feed to the console (textArea).
 * This will die after 1 minute.
 */
package application;

public class AppMain implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int i = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 60000)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {}
            System.out.println("This is line number " + ++i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really great idea, and I'm sure it works for Mac's voice over (which is a pretty good screenreading tool), but it doesn't work for NVDA. I'm not really sure why, because I know you're "selecting" the text for the screenreader to use and even executing via accessibility. It might be a problem with NVDA, but because its such a popular screenreader I can't ignore it.

Comment: That's too bad it didn't work for you. Thanks for trying it out.